# Question regarding Inheritance and Classes in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I'm trying to access objects in another class.  However the current class I'm working on is already inheriting another class.  As I understand VB.net dosen't allow for multiple inheritance.

Example:

Page 1

```
Partial Class Class1
    Inherits SomeControllerPage

    Protected Overrides Sub Load()
        Controller.GetTypes(var)  ' <---This is coming from SomeControllerPage I need to access this method in another page
    End Sub

End Class
```

Page 2

```
Partial Class Class1
        Inherits SomeOtherClass ' <--I tried changing this to SomeControllerPage and no compiler errors however it throws an error regarding the lack of System.Web.UI which is not part of SomeControllerPage but part of SomeOtherClass
    
    Protected Overrides Sub DoWork()

        Dim Controller as SomeControllerPage ' <---- I can't access GetTypes within Controller


    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: It's not just VB, .NET in general does not support multiple inheritance.  If you want to delegate implementation, you'll need to work with containment (which, as you've noted, will limit you to the public interface).  If all you want is "appearance," you can get that effect with interfaces, as objects are allowed to implement an arbitrary number of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance
One of the most important concepts in object-oriented programming is that of inheritance. Inheritance allows us to define a class in terms of another class which makes it easier to create and maintain an application. This also provides an opportunity to reuse the code functionality and fast implementation time.

When creating a class, instead of writing completely new data members and member functions, the programmer can designate that the new class should inherit the members of an existing class. This existing class is called the base class, and the new class is referred to as the derived class.

Base & Derived Classes
A class can be derived from more than one class or interface, which means that it can inherit data and functions from multiple base classes or interfaces.

The syntax used in VB.Net for creating derived classes is as follows −

```
<access-specifier> Class <base_class>
...
End Class
Class <derived_class>: Inherits <base_class>
...
End Class
```

Consider a base class Shape and its derived class Rectangle −

```
' Base class
Class Shape
   Protected width As Integer
   Protected height As Integer
   Public Sub setWidth(ByVal w As Integer)
      width = w
   End Sub
   Public Sub setHeight(ByVal h As Integer)
      height = h
   End Sub
End Class
' Derived class
Class Rectangle : Inherits Shape
   Public Function getArea() As Integer
      Return (width * height)
   End Function
End Class
Class RectangleTester
   Shared Sub Main()
      Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle()
      rect.setWidth(5)
      rect.setHeight(7)
      ' Print the area of the object.
      Console.WriteLine("Total area: {0}", rect.getArea())
      Console.ReadKey()
   End Sub  
End Class
```

When the above code is compiled and executed, it produces the following result −

> Total area: 35

Base Class Initialization
The derived class inherits the base class member variables and member methods. Therefore, the super class object should be created before the subclass is created. The super class or the base class is implicitly known as MyBase in VB.Net

The following program demonstrates this −

```
' Base class
Class Rectangle
   Protected width As Double
   Protected length As Double
   Public Sub New(ByVal l As Double, ByVal w As Double)
      length = l
      width = w
   End Sub
   Public Function GetArea() As Double
      Return (width * length)
   End Function
   Public Overridable Sub Display()
      Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length)
      Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width)
      Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea())
   End Sub
   'end class Rectangle  
End Class

'Derived class
Class Tabletop : Inherits Rectangle
   Private cost As Double
   Public Sub New(ByVal l As Double, ByVal w As Double)
      MyBase.New(l, w)
   End Sub
   Public Function GetCost() As Double
      Dim cost As Double
      cost = GetArea() * 70
      Return cost
   End Function
   Public Overrides Sub Display()
      MyBase.Display()
      Console.WriteLine("Cost: {0}", GetCost())
   End Sub
    'end class Tabletop
End Class
Class RectangleTester
   Shared Sub Main()
      Dim t As Tabletop = New Tabletop(4.5, 7.5)
      t.Display()
      Console.ReadKey()
   End Sub
End Class
```

When the above code is compiled and executed, it produces the following result −

> Length: 4.5 Width: 7.5 Area: 33.75 Cost: 2362.5

VB.Net supports multiple inheritance.

Source:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_classes_objects.htm

Comment: I tried the New keyword, seems to be the same as w/o.  I can access a Property, but not the rest of SomControllerPage

Comment: I edited the post on this topic. Relevant source written above

Comment: VB most certainly does *not* support multiple inheritance.  More generally, this answer seems like a tutorial on inheritance, but the question isn't about getting a general tutorial on inheritance.  In fact, the question seems to understand inheritance just fine.